# AVCaptureMetadataOutput delegate method is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I want to scan QR code using `AVFoundation > AVCaptureMetadataOutput` class. My code as below,

```
@interface QRScannerViewController : UIViewController<AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate>{

- (void)startReading {
    NSError *error;
    
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];
    
    if(!deviceInput) {
        NSLog(@"deviceInput Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
_captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
[_captureSession addInput:deviceInput];

capturedMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[_captureSession addOutput:capturedMetadataOutput];
capturedMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode];        
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [capturedMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
    [capturedMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];
    
    _videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
    
    [_viewPreview.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];
        
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self->_captureSession startRunning];
    });
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray<__kindof AVMetadataObject *> *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    
    if (metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count > 0) {
        
        NSLog(@"%@", [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0]);
         
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why my `captureOutput:output didOutputMetadataObjects:metadataObjects fromConnectionconnection` not getting call. I set AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode metadata value to AVCaptureMetadataOutput.

Answer (score -1):

Did you remember to claim the delagate? self.delagate =  QRScannerViewController

Comment: [capturedMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
this line is conform protocol.

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm use to working in swift. I meant at the Class declaration but I see you have it. I'm not used to seeing it in objective c anymore.

Comment: its nothing to related swift and objective-C classes. Yes, your syntax is valid for normal delegate assignment but in AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate there is different signature for delegate assignment.